# aix: how to sort ps by stime?

Tags: aix, sort, ps

On AIX,  for the top 10 cpu processes, I use

```
ps aux | head -1; ps aux | sort -rn +2 | head -10
```

for the top 10 mem processes

```
ps aux | head -1; ps aux | sort -rn +3 | head -10
```

How can I sort the output by stime?

stime is column 9 but

```
ps aux | head -1; ps aux | sort -rn +8 | head -10
```

Gives me this result --  not sort by stime

```
user 14614674  0,0  0,0  168  176  pts/0 T    14:23:23  0:00 cat 
user 13041722  0,0  0,0  168  176  pts/0 T    14:25:59  0:00 cat 
user 12517628  0,0  0,0  168  176  pts/0 T    14:22:26  0:00 cat 
user  9043992  0,0  0,0  168  176  pts/0 T    14:23:13  0:00 cat 
user 14745724  0,0  0,0  168  176  pts/0 T    13:47:11  0:00 cat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+8` (to sort on the part of the line starting with the 9<sup>th</sup> field) or `+8 -9` (to sort on the 9<sup>th</sup> field) is the deprecated sort key specification syntax. I'd recommend switching to the modern one: `-k 9` and `-k 9,9`.

In your case here, with `-n` the sort key is parsed as a number. That is, the portion of the line that starts at the 9<sup>th</sup> field and ends at the end of the line is converted to a number, and it's that number that is used for sorting.

That means that only the hour part will be considered.

For the minutes and seconds to be considered, you could do:

```
ps aux | sort -r -k9n -k9,9
```

Then, for ties on the comparison of hours, do a lexical comparison. If the time for morning hours are written as `02:12` and not `2:12`, you can just do `sort -rk9`, that is do a lexical comparison.

Note that it will probably not work if there are processes that were started yesterday or before.

Comment: The question should have said *stime* is column 9, not 8, counting from 1.

Comment: @meuh. D'oh. Well spotted.